# How integrate multiple APIs in one search/result function

Tags: php, laravel

There are 2 different API's that have 2 different databases but catalog similar objects (music artists). They offer different kinds of information, and I'd like to integrate both of them in one profile page on our site.

However, the problem is to find the primary key belonging to a single artist of both API's. What is the best practice to do this? I have a couple of methods in mind:

1. Relevancy Based
   The user submits a search term. The search is done on both API's and each collection of results is returned. One collection is compared to the other, if there are matches they are added to a new array.

The returned view will give links to the potential artist profiles compared to the search term. If a particular artist has a returned information on both API's then their URL will look something like this:

```
website.com/artist/profile/{API1-primary-ID}/{API2-primary-ID}
```

Then this route will pull detailed information on each artist based on their respective ID's.

However, if theres no match from the first array to the 2nd then the URL for this Artist Profile link will look something like this:

```
website.com/artist/profile/{API1-primary-ID}/0
```

In the controller, then if the 2nd parameter is 0 then the appropriate view will be displayed, only showing information from the first API.

I kind of lied when I said I had different methods of solving this problem. After typing all this out, this is the best one for my situation. I guess my question is now, is there already a module in PHP or Laravel that will compare arrays or strings for matches?

Comment: What are your criteria for relevancy?

Comment: Artist's name, upper or lowercase not strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laraval has a [ton of helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers) for doing a lot of things with arrays. If you can get the two result sets as Eloquent Collections, you can use a lot of really handy methods for comparing sets such as `intersect()`. You can see a full list of the Collection capabilities [here](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html).

As a quick tip, if your results are an associative array, you can turn them into an Eloquent Collection by doing this:

```
$myArray = array('artist' => 'Garth Brooks', 'category' => 'Country'); 
$myCollection = Collection::make($myArray);
```

If they are JSON and you do a `json_decode()` converting it into an object, you can then use [get_object_vars()](https://www.php.net/get_object_vars) to convert it into an associative array and feed it into the `Collection::make()` method.

Hopefully that gives you a few ideas on how to work with your data.